# NullPointerException while calling functions on RemoteWindow

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am working with the ChromeDriver and I am successfully able to launch the browser and load pages using getUrl(). I followed the steps mentioned here: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver and everything works fine. However, when I try to get the size of the browser window, I get a NullPointerExpception in the code:

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
```

I also checked that "driver.manage().window()" returns a "RemoteWindow" object and is not null. Other calls like getPosition() also throw a null pointer expception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions$RemoteWindow.getSize(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
```

Or:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions$RemoteWindow.getPosition(RemoteWebDriver.java:607)
```

Has anyone else seen similar issues with ChromeDriver? Any solution or ideas would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `manage().window()` API is relatively new to `WebDriver` and as such it has not been implemented in Chrome yet.

You can follow this issue for updates:
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=174

Comment: I see. Thanks for the information. I will keep a track at the progress to know when the manage() api supports chrome.